# How to align glyphicon with first line of accordion title

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see my demo: http://www.bootply.com/COm6fikZKx

I'm thinking about aligning 2 glyphicons- 
'down arrow' when the collapse is open and 'right arrow' when the collapse is closed.

It's problematic when the accordion heading/title comes to 2 lines and mobile version

How can I make the glyphicon always align with the first line to the left and not fall down to the last line of the text?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has been modified. check the example code here [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/NAkNNK?editors=1100). It will fix your issue.. :)

```
.panel-title {
  position: relative;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: block;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e114";
  /*glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right*/
  color: #333f48;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e080";
  /*glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down*/
  color: #333f48;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer! But I found for some reason it did not work to fix the issue. Can you take a look at the demo after adding your suggested css style and resize the browser to see the mobile style? Thank you! http://www.bootply.com/COm6fikZKx

Comment: Above answer has been updated please check the example link also... :)

Comment: Your Welcome.. :)